# android position view inside layout

Tags: android, android-layout

My activity has a background image 1280x800 pixels. I set it using `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`.

There's a flagstaff depicted on a background image and I need to position another image ("flag") above the flagstaff.

If device's screen dimension was exactly 1280x800, then "flag"'s position would be (850, 520). But screen size can vary and Android scales and shifts the background image accordingly to `centerCrop` flag. Hence I need to assign somehow scale and shift to "flag" image to make it placed nicely above the flagstaff.

I have examined ImageView.java and found that scaleType is used to set a `private Matrix mDrawMatrix`. But I have no read access to this field as it's private.

So, given

```
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout()
{
    ImageView bg = ...;
    ImageView flag = ...;
    int bgImageWidth = 1280;
    int bgImageHeight = 800;
    int flagPosX = 850;
    int flagPosY = 520;
    // What should I do here to place flag nicely?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the size of the screen (`context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels`, `context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels`;) and calculate what is visible from the image, for example you could do something like this (haven't really tested it but you should get the idea):

```
private void placeFlag(Context context) {
    ImageView bg = new ImageView(context);
    ImageView flag = new ImageView(context);
    int bgImageWidth = 1280;
    int bgImageHeight = 800;
    int flagPosX = 850;
    int flagPosY = 520;

    int screenWidth = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int screenHeight = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

    //calculate the proportions between the width of the bg and the screen
    double widthScale = (double) bgImageWidth / (double) screenWidth;
    double heightScale = (double) bgImageHeight / (double) screenHeight;

    //see the real scale used, it will be the maximum between the 2 values because you are using crop
    double realScale = Math.max(widthScale, heightScale);
    //calculate the position for the flag
    int flagRealX = (int) (flagPosX * realScale);
    int flagRealY = (int) (flagPosY * realScale);
}
```

Also, you should be doing that in the method `onGlobalLayout`, you could do this in `onCreate()` or inside the constructor if you want a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a LayerDrawable  approach here to make one drawable image in it's static (In which you can set background image and icon on top of background image in custom_drawable.xml and can use that file as single drawable in activity).For reference go to [android developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html). Otherwise 
For scale  issue according to different  [device resolution](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) put images in different drawable folder and can also design layout different .